# Text inside paragraph, vertical-align issue

Tags: html, css

I am having some issues vertical centering text in a `<p>`, some of the text is formatted with a span to change color of it, that colored text centers well, but the other one stays baseline aligned...

Please check my demo with the bug here, example code is provided.

Some CSS code is in Less, its the way I code my CSS. Should not be a problem.

DEMO: http://www.cssdesk.com/PeUAB

Forgot to include it first time.

Comment: Forgot to add your code?

Comment: Can't tell without your code, but if you know the height of the paragraph container, you can use a `line-height` hack: http://jsfiddle.net/Lfmp39jf/2/

Comment: Included code, sry. Copy + paste didnt worked well first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved : [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/75jvkj99/1/)

Just remove `vertical-align: middle`; as below.

```
p.Description span {
  color: @light-text;
}

p.Description span.Glow-Green {
    color: @glow-green;
    text-shadow: 1px 0 1px fade(@black, 75%);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```